# How can I get EntityManager in BaseDao (Maven+JSF+hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, hibernate-entitymanager

I have JSF maven project with Hibernate. There are some DAO classes in project, but it have failed implementation I think.

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                    applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

In each DAO I call this method

```
Session mySession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

And After that doing transactions.

Now I want create generic **`BaseDAO`** class and create base CRUD operations in it. But I need get `EntityManager`. How can I `getEntityManager` in my BaseDao?

In spring I do it:

```
public class BaseJpaDao<E> implements BaseDao<E>{
    protected Class<?> entityClass;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "mainDataBase")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public BaseJpaDao(Class<?> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    @Override
    public E persist(E e) {
        entityManager.persist(e);
        return e;
    }
```

But how do it in not spring project?

Answer (score 0):

Use Hibernates factory methods:

```
// Use persistence.xml configuration
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mainDataBase")
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
// Retrieve an application managed entity manager    
// Work with the EM
em.close();
```

Taken from the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/#d0e996).

Comment: What means this option -myPersistenceContext I need set path to myPersistenceContext.xml?

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be persistence-unit. You should create a [persistence.xml](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cfgdepds005.htm) in src/META.INF (or src/main/resources/META-INF, if its a maven project) and name the unit like you did in your spring configuration.